# Bind DataContext to Current Item in data source using c# code

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I know how to bind to the current Item in a Data Source using *XAML*. Just make the source a resource, set the `DataContext` to the resource, add a binding `Items/`.

My question is how do you bind to the current item using `c#`?

I have an *Edit* option where I set the context to a new item:

```
border.DataContext = new Item();
```

When user clicks *save* I update the data source:

```
(Master.ItemsSource as Items)[Master.SelectedIndex] = (Item)border.DataContext;
```

Now I'm stuck how do I get the DataContext of the `border` back to the current item using c# code?

```
border.DataContext = ???
```

**Edit**

My `XAML` code is:

```
<Border DataContext="{Binding Items/}" Name="border">
    ...
</Border>
```

My question is if I change the DataContext in code how do I get back the above Binding?

Comment: Are you saying you want to set `border.DataContext` to whatever "current Item" is? What is your actual problem, in terms comprehensible to somebody who isn't already familiar with your own unique way of using WPF? If that's not possible, then share enough code so we can figure out what all this stuff means.

Comment: I urge you to learn MVVM before starting your next project with WPF. You won't have to spend so much time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Are you saying that in MVVM you don't bind using the "{Binding Items/}"  notation?

Comment: I'm saying you're asking for a solution to a problem you refuse to describe. From the few hints you've dropped, I can't form any useful picture of what your design might look like.

Comment: This sentence communicates **nothing** to me: *"if I change the DataContext in code how do I get back the above Binding?"* I have never, in six years of WPF and Silverlight, and many hundreds of XAML questions on SO, seen or heard of the concept of "get back a Binding". Looking at your solution below, I *still* have no idea what you meant to signify by those words. I also don't understand why you refused to say you were working with a collection view, or what the actual problem was. Well, anyway, you figured it out.

Comment: You could have just pasted in some code and cleared up all the confusion immediately.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I guess I'm too much of a minimalist and my English needs some help. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @EdPlunkett sorry for bothering again but had to tell you. I just read your blog https://swissarmycrowbar.wordpress.com/2016/05/19/first-blog-post/ and it answers my above question. Thank you.

Comment: That's great, glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting a lot of downvotes, at least I figured it out:

It's:

```
border.SetBinding(DataContextProperty, "Items/");
```